# Modify/Upgrade Ubuntu "Minimal" Installation

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 using **minimal** option, can I upgrade it to **Full "Normal"** installation without having to reinstall the full system

Comment: did you try installing ubuntu-desktop. In a terminal: sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Didn't try, though there is a direct method for upgrading :)

Will try and update accordingly.

Comment: @Jean-Marie, already installed :(
----
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.417).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.